# Add single row in a existing table

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my code which take attributes in the selected block and aprint its table in the dwg file.

But the problem is that my heading is attribute.tag and its content is `attribute.textstring` and in my table the heading is not printed instead the record start from the beginning. Please suggest me the solution for the same.

```
   namespace TableCreation
    {
    public class Commands
    {
    // Set up some formatting constants
    // for the table

    private const double colWidth = 15.0;
    private const double rowHeight = 3.0;
    private const double textHeight = 1.0;

    private const CellAlignment cellAlign =
      CellAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    // Helper function to set text height
    // and alignment of specific cells,
    // as well as inserting the text

    static public void SetCellText(Table tb, int row, int col, string value)
    {
        tb.SetAlignment(row, col, cellAlign);
        tb.SetTextHeight(row, col, textHeight);
        tb.SetTextString(row, col, value);
    }

    [CommandMethod("BAT")]
    static public void BlockAttributeTable()
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        PromptStringOptions opt = new PromptStringOptions("\nEnter name of block to list: ");
        PromptResult pr = ed.GetString(opt);

        if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            string blockToFind = pr.StringResult.ToUpper();

            Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
            using (tr)
            {
                // Let's check the block exists

                BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                if (!bt.Has(blockToFind))
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock " + blockToFind + " does not exist.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // And go through looking for
                    // attribute definitions

                    StringCollection colNames = new StringCollection();

                    BlockTableRecord bd = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[blockToFind], OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (ObjectId adId in bd)
                    {
                        DBObject adObj = tr.GetObject(adId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                        // For each attribute definition we find...

                        AttributeDefinition ad = adObj as AttributeDefinition;
                        if (ad != null)
                        {
                            // ... we add its name to the list

                            colNames.Add(ad.Tag);
                            ed.WriteMessage("\n" + ad.Tag);
                        }
                    }
                    if (colNames.Count == 0)
                    {
                        ed.WriteMessage("\nThe block " + blockToFind + " contains no attribute definitions.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Ask the user for the insertion point
                        // and then create the table

                        PromptPointResult ppr;
                        PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
                        ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
                        //get the coordinates from user
                        ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
                        if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                            return;
                        Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
                        //Point3d startPoint1 = startPoint.Subtract();
                        Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);
                        Vector3d disp2 = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);

                        if (ppr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
                        {
                            Table tb = new Table();
                            tb.TableStyle = db.Tablestyle;
                            tb.NumRows = 1;
                            tb.NumColumns = colNames.Count;
                            tb.SetRowHeight(rowHeight);
                            tb.SetColumnWidth(colWidth);
                            tb.Position = startPoint;

                            // Let's add our column headings

                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                            {
                                SetCellText(tb, 0, i, colNames[i]);
                                //ed.WriteMessage("\n" + colNames[i]);
                            }

                            // Now let's search for instances of
                            // our block in the modelspace

                            BlockTableRecord ms = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace], OpenMode.ForRead);

                            int rowNum = 1;
                            foreach (ObjectId objId in ms)
                            {
                                DBObject obj = tr.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                BlockReference br = obj as BlockReference;
                                if (br != null)
                                {
                                    BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                    using (btr)
                                    {
                                        if (btr.Name.ToUpper() == blockToFind)
                                        {
                                            // We have found one of our blocks,
                                            // so add a row for it in the table

                                            tb.InsertRows(rowNum, rowHeight, 2);

                                            // Assume that the attribute refs
                                            // follow the same order as the
                                            // attribute defs in the block

                                            int attNum = 0;
                                            foreach (ObjectId arId in br.AttributeCollection)
                                            {
                                                DBObject arObj = tr.GetObject(arId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                                AttributeReference ar = arObj as AttributeReference;
                                                if (ar != null)
                                                {
                                                    string strCell;

                                                    strCell = ar.TextString;

                                                    string strArId = arId.ToString();

                                                    strArId = strArId.Trim(new char[] { '(', ')' });

                                                    SetCellText(tb, rowNum, attNum, strCell);
                                                    ed.WriteMessage("\n" + ar.Tag);
                                                }
                                                attNum++;
                                            }
                                            rowNum++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            tb.GenerateLayout();

                            ms.UpgradeOpen();
                            ms.AppendEntity(tb);
                            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(tb, true);
                            tr.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the current table style (db.Tablestyle) in which the first row is a 'title' row (merged cells).
You can use this first row to display the block name, use the second row for the headers and start filling the values in the third one.

```
    // Set up some formatting constants
    // for the table

    private const double colWidth = 15.0;
    private const double rowHeight = 3.0;
    private const double textHeight = 1.0;
    private const CellAlignment cellAlign = CellAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    // Helper function to set text height
    // and alignment of specific cells,
    // as well as inserting the text

    static public void SetCellText(Table tb, int row, int col, string value)
    {
        tb.Cells[row, col].Alignment = cellAlign;
        tb.Cells[row, col].TextHeight = textHeight;
        tb.Cells[row, col].Value = value;
    }

    [CommandMethod("BAT")]
    static public void BlockAttributeTable()
    {
        Document doc = AcAp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        PromptStringOptions opt = new PromptStringOptions("\nEnter name of block to list: ");
        PromptResult pr = ed.GetString(opt);

        if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            string blockToFind = pr.StringResult.ToUpper();

            Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
            using (tr)
            {
                // Let's check the block exists

                BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                if (!bt.Has(blockToFind))
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock " + blockToFind + " does not exist.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // And go through looking for
                    // attribute definitions

                    StringCollection colNames = new StringCollection();

                    BlockTableRecord bd = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[blockToFind], OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (ObjectId adId in bd)
                    {
                        DBObject adObj = tr.GetObject(adId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                        // For each attribute definition we find...

                        AttributeDefinition ad = adObj as AttributeDefinition;
                        if (ad != null)
                        {
                            // ... we add its name to the list

                            colNames.Add(ad.Tag);
                            ed.WriteMessage("\n" + ad.Tag);
                        }
                    }
                    if (colNames.Count == 0)
                    {
                        ed.WriteMessage("\nThe block " + blockToFind + " contains no attribute definitions.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Ask the user for the insertion point
                        // and then create the table

                        PromptPointResult ppr;
                        PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
                        ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
                        //get the coordinates from user
                        ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
                        if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                            return;
                        Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
                        //Point3d startPoint1 = startPoint.Subtract();
                        Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);
                        Vector3d disp2 = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);

                        if (ppr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
                        {
                            Table tb = new Table();
                            tb.TableStyle = db.Tablestyle;
                            tb.SetSize(2, colNames.Count);
                            tb.SetRowHeight(rowHeight);
                            tb.SetColumnWidth(colWidth);
                            tb.Position = startPoint;

                            // Let's add the table title
                            tb.Cells[0, 0].Value = bd.Name;

                            // Let's add our column headings

                            for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Count; i++)
                            {
                                SetCellText(tb, 1, i, colNames[i]);
                                //ed.WriteMessage("\n" + colNames[i]);
                            }

                            // Now let's search for instances of
                            // our block in the modelspace

                            ObjectId msId = SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db);
                            BlockTableRecord ms = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(msId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                            int rowNum = 2;
                            foreach (ObjectId brId in bd.GetBlockReferenceIds(true, true))
                            {
                                BlockReference br = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(brId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                if (br.OwnerId == msId)
                                {
                                    // We have found one of our blocks,
                                    // so add a row for it in the table

                                    tb.InsertRows(rowNum, rowHeight, 1);

                                    // Assume that the attribute refs
                                    // follow the same order as the
                                    // attribute defs in the block

                                    int attNum = 0;
                                    foreach (ObjectId arId in br.AttributeCollection)
                                    {
                                        DBObject arObj = tr.GetObject(arId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                        AttributeReference ar = arObj as AttributeReference;
                                        if (ar != null)
                                        {
                                            string strCell = ar.TextString;

                                            string strArId = arId.ToString().Trim('(', ')');

                                            SetCellText(tb, rowNum, attNum, strCell);
                                            ed.WriteMessage("\n" + ar.Tag);
                                        }
                                        attNum++;
                                    }
                                    rowNum++;
                                }
                            }
                            tb.GenerateLayout();

                            ms.AppendEntity(tb);
                            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(tb, true);
                            tr.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to type block name every time. I want to select one block and according to that name print the output for same block in the drawing